# Struggling to capture the text input of an html form from Google Apps Scripts to log on a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, google-apps-script

-----Updated working code is on the bottom-----

-----Updated [Git Here](https://gist.github.com/4n7h0ny/a5e89916dfa596e0b1831347b478ec4e) --------

I have a google apps script that is currently working that allows bulk file uploads without a log in, uploads the files to a drive, and logs the file info on a spreadsheet.  I also want to capture a text input field from the html form to capture that as well.  I have been struggling over the past two weeks and have made zero progress on the matter, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have made a git  https://gist.github.com/4n7h0ny/c879c72888db1a2cd891f6f83db7e332

webapp url - https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby59WOCrFAUhM3o13PGiDPMyrkp9qeFhuqKnoSJBHTn6rBOfJroue29TU-lgxlsgRAX6g/exec

I want to capture this part of the html form

```
type  <TEXTAREA name="projectDescription" 
          id="projectDesctiptionIndex"
          placeholder="Index"
          style ="width:400px; height:200px;"
          ></TEXTAREA>here
```

Code.gs code

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}


    var sid = '1eQIZESbrhst6FUza8t_SEwy5bnKBTarNwDDuIVKsLiw';  //URL OF GOOGLE SHEET;


function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(fileName);

    
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1h7hMHz7XD1oFKFY_jotrcVdq6Bn0uXfY");

  

    var file = folder.createFile(ss);

    console.log(file);

    var ssss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sid).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    ssss.appendRow([file.getName(), file.getUrl(), Date()]);

   

    return file.getName();
  }catch(e){
    return 'Error: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
```

form.html code

```
<body>
  <div id="formcontainer">



    <br><br>


    <form id="myForm"> 
      <div>


      </div>
      <div>

      <label for="fileText" id="fileTextIndex" >Index:</label>

          <TEXTAREA name="projectDescription" 
          id="projectDesctiptionIndex"
          placeholder="Index"
          style ="width:400px; height:200px;"
          ></TEXTAREA>


      </div> 
      <br>



      <label for="myFile">Upload Attachment(s):</label>
      <br>


      <input type="file" name="filename" id="myFile" multiple>

      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="iteratorFileUpload()">


    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="output"></div>
<div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress-label"></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>

var numUploads = {};
numUploads.done = 0;
numUploads.total = 0;

// Upload the files into a folder in drive
// This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
function iteratorFileUpload() {
    var allFiles = document.getElementById('myFile').files;

    if (allFiles.length == 0) {
        alert('No file selected!');
    } else {
        //Show Progress Bar

        numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
        $('#progressbar').progressbar({
        value : false
        });//.append("<div class='caption'>37%</div>");
        $(".progress-label").html('Preparing files for upload');
        // Send each file at a time
        for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i]);
        }
    }
}

function sendFileToDrive(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var content = reader.result;
        console.log('Sending ' + file.name);
        var currFolder = 'Something';
          
        
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, currFolder);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function updateProgressbar( idUpdate ){
   console.log('Received: ' + idUpdate);
   numUploads.done++;
   var porc = Math.ceil((numUploads.done / numUploads.total)*100);
   $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: porc });
   $(".progress-label").text(numUploads.done +'/'+ numUploads.total);
   if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){
      //uploadsFinished();
      numUploads.done = 0;
   };
}
</script>

  <script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
      document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }

  </script>

  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 400px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    input {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      ‌​ -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    select {
      margin: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      width: auto !important;
      display: block !important;
    }
    input[type="file"] {
      padding: 5px 0px 15px 0px !important;
    }
#progressbar{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.progress-label {
      float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
          width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

I have tried using the

```
document.getElementById('projectDesctiptionIndex').innerHTLM = PROJECTDESCRIPTION
```

but I do not understand this method enough to pull back to the JS side of things and after 80+ iterations of failure this is something I simply can not figure out on my own as of now.

---------------Updated working code that logs everything with a huge thank you to Tanaike for helping me keep my sanity and get through this wall I hit. -----------------

```
Code.gs

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}


    var sid = '1eQIZESbrhst6FUza8t_SEwy5bnKBTarNwDDuIVKsLiw';  //ID OF GOOGLE SHEET;


function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName,textY, textIndex, textDescription) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(fileName);

    
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1h7hMHz7XD1oFKFY_jotrcVdq6Bn0uXfY");  //Google Drive folder ID of the folder the files get uploaded to
  
  
       
  
    
    var file = folder.createFile(ss);

    console.log(file);

    var ssss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sid).getSheetByName("Sheet4");


    console.log(decodeURI(textDescription));

    ssss.appendRow([file.getName(), file.getUrl(), Date(), file.getId(), "0", textDescription, textIndex]);
 
    return file.getName();
      }catch(e){
    return 'Error: ' + e.toString();
  }

  
}
```

form.html

```
<body>
  <div id="formcontainer">



  


    <form id="myForm"> 
      <br>
      <div>

             <label for="projectDescription" >Index:</label>
             <input type="text" name="projectDescription1" id="idIndex" placeholder="Index">


             <label for="projectDescription555" >Description:</label>
             <input type="text" name="projectDescription5551" id="idText" placeholder="Description">
             </div>
          
            


   
     



      <!-- <label for="myFile">Upload Attachment(s):</label> -->
   

      <br>


      <input type="file" name="filename" id="myFile" multiple>

      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="iteratorFileUpload()">


    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="output"></div>
<div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress-label"></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>

var numUploads = {};
numUploads.done = 0;
numUploads.total = 0;

// Upload the files into a folder in drive
// This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
function iteratorFileUpload() {
    var allFiles = document.getElementById('myFile').files;

    if (allFiles.length == 0) {
        alert('No file selected!');
    } else {
        //Show Progress Bar

        numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
        $('#progressbar').progressbar({
        value : false
        });//.append("<div class='caption'>37%</div>");
        $(".progress-label").html('Preparing files for upload');
        // Send each file at a time
        for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i]);
        }
    }
}

function sendFileToDrive(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var content = reader.result;
        console.log('Sending ' + file.name);
        var currFolder = 'Something';
          var textIndex = document.getElementById("idIndex").value;
          var textDescription = document.getElementById("idText").value;
          var textY = document.getElementById("idText").value;
  
        
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, currFolder, textIndex, textDescription, textY);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function updateProgressbar( idUpdate ){
   console.log('Received: ' + idUpdate);
   numUploads.done++;
   var porc = Math.ceil((numUploads.done / numUploads.total)*100);
   $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: porc });
   $(".progress-label").text(numUploads.done +'/'+ numUploads.total);
      if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){

   var text = document.getElementById("idText").value;
   var text1 = document.getElementById("idIndex").value;
   google.script.run.putText(text, text1);

   uploadsFinished();
   numUploads.done = 0;
};
 
 
 
  //  if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){
  //     //uploadsFinished();
  //     numUploads.done = 0;
  //  };
}
</script>

  <script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
      document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }

  </script>

  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 400px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    input {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      ‌​ -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    select {
      margin: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      width: auto !important;
      display: block !important;
    }
    input[type="file"] {
      padding: 5px 0px 15px 0px !important;
    }
#progressbar{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.progress-label {
      float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
          width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: When you open the form there is a place to enter some text, I would like this text to also be logged onto the spreadsheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your script, it seems that you want to use `google.script.run` with the asynchronous process. In this case, when `I would like this text to also be logged onto the spreadsheet` is run, what result do you want to expect? Unfortunately, I cannot still imagine your expected result. I apologize for this.

Comment: Ok ill try to explain better:
when this link is clicked

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby59WOCrFAUhM3o13PGiDPMyrkp9qeFhuqKnoSJBHTn6rBOfJroue29TU-lgxlsgRAX6g/exec

 and files are uploaded the data is logged to this spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eQIZESbrhst6FUza8t_SEwy5bnKBTarNwDDuIVKsLiw/edit#gid=0

There is a place to input text on the form and I want that to be placed on the spreadsheet too, I have uploaded some screenshots here

https://photos.app.goo.gl/ZbeqC6i4JwdBPQvR9

https://photos.app.goo.gl/fWwYbfsSj6nWyYGo9

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your reply, I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the files are uploaded by clicking a button, you want to also put the text of the text area tag to Spreadsheet.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, both Javascript and Google Apps Script are modified.

#### Javascript side:

Please modify the function `updateProgressbar` of Javascript as follows.

##### From:

```
if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){
   //uploadsFinished();
   numUploads.done = 0;
};
```

##### To:

```
if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){

   // I added the below script.
   var text = document.getElementById("projectDesctiptionIndex").value;
   google.script.run.putText(text);

   //uploadsFinished();
   numUploads.done = 0;
};
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please add the following function to Google Apps Script.

```
function putText(text) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sid).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange("D" + sheet.getLastRow()).setValue(text);
}
```

- By the above modification, when you set the files and a value to the text area tag and click "Submit" button, the files are uploaded and the inputted text is put into column "D".
- In your showing sample image, it seems that you want to put the text in column "C". But, in your script, it seems that column "C" is the date. So, I put the text in column "D". Please be careful about this.

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have been trying to figure this out for almost three weeks, you have helped me so much!